# Is it possible to see the routing table at the gateway (next-hop) router?

Tags: routing, ip-routing, iproute2

Suppose the output of the "route -n" (on Red Hat/Debian) command is as follows:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         a.b.c.d         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 venet0
```

Given that the the gateway (next-hop router) IP is a.b.c.d, is it possible on the host machine to show the routing table at this particular gateway? or do I have to contact the administrator of the router at a.b.c.d to find out?

Comment: I don't believe that it is possible and I shudder to think of the possible ramifications if it were.

Comment: @joeqwerty Stole your answer, dawg! =P

Comment: You could use SNMPwalk with the proper OID, if SNMP is configured on the router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routing table information is privileged and can only be seen by unauthenticated users in cases where one of the following is true:

- The administrator of the next hop device has left it in an insecure
  state that allows anonymous access.
- The administrator of the next hop device has created some kind of
  special and intentional public interface to show the routing tables.

Answer (score 1):

Some providers will give you a read only view of their routes, but it's usually something you have to request.